# Get Cursor of given path

Tags: android, sql, uri, android-contentresolver

I have uri object that contains real path of an image. I know that we need to use selection string while query but i am bad at sql.

How can i get the cursor represent that image?

This is my projection string for my DTO.

```
  String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.WIDTH,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.HEIGHT,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};
```

And the Uri returns from cropping library.

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
    } else if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        final Throwable cropError = UCrop.getError(data);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: "I have uri object that contains real path of an image" -- that is very unlikely. [Please use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). For example, most [image-loading libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) know how to populate an `ImageView` from a `Uri`. Or, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, then pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`, all on a background thread.

Comment: I am using a crop library which returns Uri. You can check it it out from editted question. There is nothing wrong with it. Thanks anyway. Cheers.

Comment: You would need to ask the author of the library what the rules are for the returned `Uri`.

Comment: You were right. Best way to achive cropped image is decoding. Because library requires a file path that can save cropped image which i gave cache dir to avoid writing disk permission. So the way i did is path to file then decoding as a bitmap and migrating it to my DTO. That was a bad way for me because having a bitmap is forcing memory to getting down. Sadly, no other way so far. If you can write an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a `Uri` does not have to represent a file on the filesystem, let alone have a path that you can determine, let alone be a file that you can access.

For a `Uri` whose scheme is `file`, `getPath()` returns the filesystem path to the file. However, you may not have read or write access to that file through the filesystem (though this would indicate a coding error on the part of whoever created the `Uri` and gave it to you).

For any other sort of `Uri` — the most common being those with a `content` scheme — there is no way to determine a filesystem path, because there is no requirement that the content be an ordinary file. It might be an encrypted file, content stored in a `BLOB` column in a database, content to be downloaded from the network, or countless other patterns.